# Pandas make all values in a column 1 after a particular value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, I want to check each column and if a value ever hits .92 or below I want to change every value after it to 1.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean to check each column from top to bottom and within a column if a value hits 0.92 or below you want to change every value after that value (in that column) to 1 ?

Comment: Sorry I should have written the frame out but I'm on a phone and it's a pain... but basically if the column values are 1.01, .98, .97, .92, .93, .91 then I would want the column to change to 1.01, .98, .97, .92, 1, 1.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there some pattern in the columns as well. In your example i can see the values are in descending order or is it just a coincidence.

Comment: Well they aren't in descending order,  .92, .93, .91 for example.  But there isn't a pattern to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 10) * 10, columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ')).round(2)
```

Use `cumprod` on a boolean dataframe.  Then use that in `pd.DataFrame.where`

```
df.where(df.gt(.92).cumprod().astype(bool), 1)

      A     B    C     D     E    F     G     H     I     J
0  4.45  4.08  4.6  4.65  4.63  1.0  8.50  8.18  7.78  7.58
1  9.35  8.31  8.8  9.27  7.22  1.0  1.46  2.00  4.38  1.01
2  2.79  6.10  1.0  8.37  7.40  1.0  6.91  3.77  2.25  4.35
3  7.01  7.01  1.0  1.00  7.01  1.0  7.65  2.53  5.48  7.79
4  6.52  1.36  1.0  1.00  2.75  1.0  7.14  7.76  5.42  8.37
5  5.38  1.86  1.0  1.00  3.74  1.0  7.76  1.00  5.04  6.71
6  6.20  3.02  1.0  1.00  3.68  1.0  8.82  1.00  4.96  8.06
7  1.00  4.38  1.0  1.00  1.00  1.0  5.85  1.00  6.39  1.33
8  1.00  8.82  1.0  1.00  1.00  1.0  1.00  1.00  6.06  4.02
9  1.00  6.41  1.0  1.00  1.00  1.0  1.00  1.00  1.09  3.15
```

---

Something about my solution bothered me.  So I [**asked my own question here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44555397/2336654).  This is a better solution considering the advice from the linked question.  Please consider following the link and showing appreciation for the question and answer.  Thanks.

```
v = df.values
mask = np.logical_and.accumulate(v > .92, 0)
pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(mask, v, 1),
    df.index, df.columns
)

      A     B    C     D     E    F     G     H     I     J
0  4.45  4.08  4.6  4.65  4.63  1.0  8.50  8.18  7.78  7.58
1  9.35  8.31  8.8  9.27  7.22  1.0  1.46  2.00  4.38  1.01
2  2.79  6.10  1.0  8.37  7.40  1.0  6.91  3.77  2.25  4.35
3  7.01  7.01  1.0  1.00  7.01  1.0  7.65  2.53  5.48  7.79
4  6.52  1.36  1.0  1.00  2.75  1.0  7.14  7.76  5.42  8.37
5  5.38  1.86  1.0  1.00  3.74  1.0  7.76  1.00  5.04  6.71
6  6.20  3.02  1.0  1.00  3.68  1.0  8.82  1.00  4.96  8.06
7  1.00  4.38  1.0  1.00  1.00  1.0  5.85  1.00  6.39  1.33
8  1.00  8.82  1.0  1.00  1.00  1.0  1.00  1.00  6.06  4.02
9  1.00  6.41  1.0  1.00  1.00  1.0  1.00  1.00  1.09  3.15
```

---

**Timing**

```
%timeit df.where(df.gt(.92).cumprod().astype(bool), 1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 844 µs per loop

%%timeit
v = df.values
mask = np.logical_and.accumulate(v > .92, 0)
pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(mask, v, 1),
    df.index, df.columns
)
10000 loops, best of 3: 65.8 µs per loop
```

Comment: I've never heard of df.gt before.  So would all of the 1.00 in that df be 0.92 or less before the .gt call?

Comment: @James I gave you the code to reconstruct the same dataframe. Take a look yourself and see. :-)

Comment: Ok thanks! I will play with the code some time tomorrow after finals and accept your answer if it works my friend!

Comment: @James I've updated my answer with a quicker solution.