# How to do a cumulative "all"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Setup**
Consider the numpy array `a`

```
>>> np.random.seed([3,1415])
>>> a = np.random.choice([True, False], (4, 8))

>>> a
array([[ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

**Question**
For each column, I want to determine the cumulative equivalent for all.

The result should look like this:

```
array([[ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Take the first column

```
a[: 0]

# Original First Column
array([ True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
# So far so good
#        \     False from here on
#         |    /---------------\
array([ True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
# Cumulative all
```

So basically, cumulative all is `True` as long as we have `True` and turns `False` from then on at the first `False`

---

**What I have tried**
I can get the result with

```
a.cumprod(0).astype(bool)
```

But, I can't help but wonder if its necessary to perform each and every multiplication when I know everything will be `False` from the first `False` I see.

Consider the larger 1-D array

```
b = np.array(list('111111111110010101010101010101010101010011001010101010101')).astype(int).astype(bool)
```

I contend that these two produce the same answer

```
bool(b.prod())
```

and

```
b.all()
```

But `b.all()` can short circuit while `b.prod()` does not.  If I time them:

```
%timeit bool(b.prod())
%timeit b.all()

100000 loops, best of 3: 2.05 µs per loop
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.45 µs per loop
```

`b.all()` is quicker.  This implies that there must me a way to conduct a cumulative all that is quicker that my `a.cumprod(0).astype(bool)`

Comment: IIRC, the `all` method on NumPy arrays actually either doesn't short-circuit or only short-circuits after processing a complete chunk of the array, for some fairly substantial (default) chunk size.

Comment: We've found in other SO questions that selected operations do short circuit, such as `min/max` involving `nan`.  But my guess is that most, if not all, `ufunc` use a generic iterator to perform `accumulate`.  That would be especially true when working along one axis.  Short circuiting in your column case would require stopping at different rows for each column.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[All ufuncs have 5 methods](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/ufuncs.html#methods): `reduce`, `accumulate`, `reduceat`, `outer`, and `at`. In this case, use `accumulate` since it returns the result of cumulative applications of the ufunc:

```
In [41]: np.logical_and.accumulate(a, axis=0)
Out[50]: 
array([[ True, False,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

---

```
In [60]: np.random.seed([3,1415])

In [61]: a = np.random.choice([True, False], (400, 80))

In [57]: %timeit np.logical_and.accumulate(a, axis=0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 85.6 µs per loop

In [59]: %timeit a.cumprod(0).astype(bool)
10000 loops, best of 3: 138 µs per loop
```

Comment: `a.cumprod(0, dtype=bool)` is a much fairer comparison, which is essentially the same speed. Using `astype` incurs a copy

Comment: Better question is why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: `np.minimum.accumulate(a, axis=0)` also works (same speed).